# No Image on all DP Monitors after Reboot, needs to boot on HDMI [Win10 GTX3060TI]

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, reboot

There are 3 identical LC-Power M27-FHD-165-C monitors connected to my GTX3060TI.

When I first set it up, after each Windows update, the Bios screen would show on one monitor and then all monitors would show no source and stay black. I then had to disconnect all three DP ports and connect the single monitor via HDMI. Then I had to reboot the PC, after booting successfully I could then reconnect the three DP and disconnect the HDMI connector.

But for a few weeks now, this has been happening after EVERY reboot. I could get away with not rebooting as often and having the cables accessible, but I'm starting to worry about the video card connections.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did anything change on the computer before or around when it began this behavior? Have you checked for updated drivers or firmware?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I remembered changing which monitor is the main monitor. I figured out if the main monitor differs from the Monitor which is showing the Bios Boot Screen then there is no signal afterwards. The screen which shows the BIOs Screen need to be the Windows Main Monitor!

Comment: That's odd. There's still something wrong if that's how your computer behaves. Yes, BIOS typically only present on the main display, that's normal. But windows should be able to use monitors other than the main without this work around.

Answer (score 0):

The Main Monitor in Windows needs to be the same Monitor as the Monitor which shows the Bios Boot Screen. Then it is working!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).